How does the phrase "Implausibly reductive" mean overly simplistic?
For more reference, this appears at the end of this passage: Barbara Tuchman’s The Guns of August is an engrossing if dated introduction to World War I. Tuchman’s analysis of primary documents is laudable, but her main thesis that European powers committed themselves to a catastrophic outcome by refusing to deviate from military plans developed prior to the conﬂict is implausibly reductive.
My reasoning is that it should mean the "something that's probably not simplistic". Implausible means something that's not probable, and reductive means simplistic. "Implausibly" is modifying the word "reductive", is it not? Then it should mean "something that's probably not simplistic". I know I am wrong though, so what are the rules behind this? Why does implausible modify Tuchman's thesis instead of the word reductive if it ends with an "ly"? Any help would be appreciated!

Welcome to ELU. By the way, “overly simplistic” is redundant because simplistic itself means “made simpler than is appropriate.”

I'd use implausibly to mean not believably more than improbably

It's the same construction as "unbelievably stupid".

Just wondering, why am I getting downvoted? Is it because I'm explaining the question badly or because I asked such a stupid question which the answer should have been obvious to me

What it means is that she reduces the causes of the catastrophic outcome to the sole cause of their refusing to drop their plans.  Hence she is reductive.

considering or presenting something in a simple way, especially a way that is too simple:

This is a simple cause.  For it to be "simplistic" it would have to be overly simplified, past reasonable.  But then, the author of that sentence does regard it past reasonable since it is deemed "implausibly."

in a way that is difficult to believe, or unlikely:

That the actual causes are more complicated is implied but not stated in the sentence; it only asserts that it was not the single cause that she ascribed to it.
